# Dynamic pans in Audiomath not completely smooth

Tags: python, audio, audiomath

I've been trying to get an effect similar to the dynamic-panning demo from in the audiomath [examples](https://audiomath.readthedocs.io/en/release/auto/Examples.html#play-sounds):

```py
import math
import audiomath as am
s = am.TestSound('12').MixDownToMono()
p = am.Player(s)
period_in_seconds = 4.0
p.Play(loop=True, pan=lambda t: math.sin(2 * math.pi * t / period_in_seconds))
```

However, the pan doesn't sound smooth: the volume swells when the sound is in the middle and fades slightly at either side. Any advice on how can I make transitions like this sound smooth?

Answer (score 0):

From the [`.pan` property docstring](https://audiomath.readthedocs.io/en/release/source/audiomath.Player.html#audiomath.Player.pan):

> The way levels are computed from scalar values between -1 and +1 depends on `.norm`.

and accordingly from the [`.norm` property docstring](https://audiomath.readthedocs.io/en/release/source/audiomath.Player.html#audiomath.Player.norm):

> For a `Player` instance `p`, if you set `p.pan` to a scalar value between -1 and +1, the relative levels of left and right channels are computed such that::
>
> `left ** p.norm + right ** p.norm = 1`
>
> The value `p.norm=2` produces a natural-sounding pan but it means that stereo sounds are reduced to 70.71% of their maximum amplitude by default. So instead, the default is to use the infinity-norm, `p.norm='inf'`, which ensures that the larger of the two sides is always 1.0

So the default setting is indeed a non-smooth pan.  Adding `norm=2` to your `Player` properties might be the way to go—that would keep total signal *power* constant across channels.  Incidentally, the most sensitive way to judge this would be by using a continuous tone stimulus like you get from [`ToneTest()`](https://audiomath.readthedocs.io/en/release/source/audiomath.html#audiomath.ToneTest):

```
import math, audiomath as am
am.RequireAudiomathVersion('1.10')

period_in_seconds = 4.0
p = am.ToneTest(norm=2, pan=lambda t: math.sin(2 * math.pi * t / period_in_seconds) )
p.Play()
# now experiment with `p.norm` while it's playing
```

You could also try `norm=1` (keeps the sum of the channel *amplitudes* constant instead of power).